# How do i add the click image and pop-up notify then open new tab?

Tags: javascript

I need help adding a click event show notification then open a new tab. to the code below so that when a user clicks the image it performs the function shown in the script.

[image]

Comment: [Please add the code to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please share what u have done. You cant begging for answer if u dont show some effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it window.open()

```js
function myFunction() {
  var result = confirm("Want to proceed?");
  if (result) {
    console.log("eveent");

    window.open(url, '_blank');

  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <p>Click the button to open a new browser window.</p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>


</body>

</html><a class="link">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```js
function myFunction() {
      var r = confirm("Press a button!");
      if (r) {
        window.open('url', '_blank');
      }
    }
```

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" onclick="myFunction()">
```

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript code

```
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(img => {

    //img.addEventListener('click', doSomething());
    // Or

  img.addEventListener('click', function(e){

   alert('You are about to open new tab');
    window.open(this.src);

})

});
```

### [Full demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3sm72roc/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="imagecoin"></div>

</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
            if(e.target && e.target.id== 'anchor1'){
                  doSomething();
             }
         });
        function doSomething() {
            alert('Open New Tab')
            var win = window.open('https://www.google.com','_blank');
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = myFunction();
        function myFunction() {
            setInterval(function () {
                document.getElementById('imagecoin').innerHTML='<img id="anchor1" src="http://i.imgur.com/YOGdNM1.png">'
            },1800)
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Since id anchor1 is append after loading, you cannot document.getElementById('anchor1')